# Dimens file not working properly with some changes in dp values

Tags: android, user-interface, dimension

When i change any dp value in one dimens file it will reflect in two devices in android

I wan to create a dimens file for 6inch screen 1080*2160 and 403 dpi which i need to compatible with my device and previously i use 4.7 inch screen with 720*1280 with 312 dpi for 4.7 inch screen, everything works good  and  now i was doing any changes in new dimen file which is xxhdpi it will reflect in both devices(4.7 and 6 inch screen)